# It's driving me crazy, 24 errors produced when I run this simple Java program.

Tags: java

```
public class Planet {
    double x;
    double y;
    double xV;
    double yV;
    double mass;
    double imgName;
    public Planet (double x; double y; double xV; double y; double mass; double imgName;) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.xV = xV;
        this.yV = yV;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.imgName = imgName;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> Planet.java:8: ')' expected
>
> Planet.java:8: illegal start of type
>
> Planet.java:8: ';' expected
>
> Planet.java:9: illegal start of type
>
> Planet.java:9:  expected
>
> Planet.java:9: ';' expected
>
> Planet.java:9: illegal start of type
>
> ...
>
> Planet.java:16: class, interface, or enum expected    public static void
>   main(String[] args)
>
> Planet.java:18: class, interface, or enum expected }

I see different types of error! Could anyone explain them one by one to me as it is so annoying.

Comment: What is the `;` character for?

Comment: [Basic official Java method tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: In the class constructor signature change the **;** for **,** (parameters are separated by commas, not semicolons). And although it's not forbidden, the idea of the `main` method is to be run from command line and your POJO should not contains this method.

Comment: Thank you. How could it produce so many errors?

Answer (score 7):

You are not declaring your parameters properly. Use:

```
public Planet (double x, double y, double xV, double y, double mass, double imgName)
```

Additionally, `main` should not return 0. If you want to return a system exit code, use `System.exit(0)`. Simply returning from the main method (using `return;` or by reaching the end of it) will act analogously to `return 0;` from main languages like C.

The reason there are so many errors is due to the way the Java parser/compiler works. The first error is already an incorrect state, so the following errors are just artifacts of the compiler being "confused".

**A practical rule of thumb for compile/syntax errors is to focus on fixing the *first* error given, as the parsing of the rest of the file is likely affected by it.**

Although I am not 100% certain I believe that the following is occuring:

1. Semicolon causes parser to emit error of missing closing `)`, and to end the statement (in fact, ending the constructor then and there).
2. After the last semicolon, `)` is an illegal type, and a semicolon is additionally expected.
3. Although nearly any human would conclude that `this.x = x` is part of the constructor, the previous line confused the parser so it thinks it's working at class scope (not in a method). It can't parse `this.x = x` because `this.x` isn't a valid type, and this "field" doesn't have a name. At this point, it is clear that the previous errors have messed up the parser state enough to begin panicking for valid statements that it now believes are out of place.
4. As it reaches the closing `}` it ends the class scope. The following main method and final closing `}` are likewise unparseable, and cause errors to be emitted (since these elements are not inside a class at this point)

Comment: Thank you and that's what I really ask for. As I rebuild the code, I see another error produced "y is already defined in Planet"...so why y? not the parameters parallel to it

Comment: @tonyabracadabra If you look in the list of parameters, you have `double y` in there twice. Looking at the rest of your code, this looks like a simple typo, since there isn't a field of `Planet` that got "left out".

Comment: Oh I apologize for that, thanks for your patience toward a newbie. : )

Comment: @tonyabracadabra Not a problem, always glad to help :) As everyone else here, I was a newbie at one point as well.